# Is it good practice to mandate input action on the password field in a webapp?

Tags: authentication, web-application, password-policy

I am of the school of thought that says you should never have the browser "remember your password" because if you use it often enough, you will be able to retain that piece of information. I now want to enforce this in the web application software we're building.
Regardless of whether the browser remembers and/or auto-fills it or not, I still think it is conducive to web application security if any user would still have to type the password. This way it is almost guranteed that the user sitting at the terminal is the user logging in.

I am now wondering why this isn't a standard as of yet.

Comment: what about password managers? Finding a site which disables paste on password fields is annoying for password manager users and encourages poor passwords (user is forced to remember it, so will naturally pick a weaker password for convenience)

Comment: @Jay: absolutely. I had one bank doing that to me and I switched banks because if the insanity of that "security measure". I know that they backpedaled afterwards but it was too late for some customers.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I guess I should've given the social engineering aspect of this more thought. I had never given thought to how this would affect user behaviour. I will reverse now reverse my decision on this.

Comment: "because if you use it often enough, you will be able to retain that piece of information" - That's a bit arrogant, why do you think I'm going to log into _your_ website that often? And what if every site did that, would people really be able to remember fifty different passwords that way? Or will they just use the same password everywhere, or a really easy password, therefore compromising security?

Comment: I second the comment about using password managers. I don't know the majority of my passwords and having to paste my password in notepad to type it all out manually is going to make me find an alternative to your website.

Comment: Remember: Security at the expense of usability comes at the expense of security.

Comment: @Random832 It's not arrogance, it's merely a statement of fact. If you use something often enough you will remember it. It's not about selling or  enticing user to use my webapp. It usually is generally the case that most users do not user more than a pool of 5 passwords for everything. Like I mentioned before I hadn't given much thought to user behaviour.

Comment: I have a 80 character master password for my password manager. Typing it in is like my hourly nightmare. If your site is incompatible with a password manager, I will definitely not use it instead of trying to remember and repeatly type another long password.

Comment: 80 Characters is excessive, but it works.  It's easy as a developer or IT to forget how users will act, even if you know how dumb they can be.  You have to make the better security choices more convenient, otherwise you end up with swiss-cheese security (look up top 10 passwords in google).  It's only as secure as the user, and most users would love to leave all their house doors unlocked and open if it means they could get to work faster (not literally).  At some point people will become more security conscious, but right now we have to persuade them to make better choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> .... because if you use it often enough,
>   you will be able to retain that piece of information.

Yes, but your approach would have side effects:

- Disabling the remember me option would lead the user will  choose an easy to remember -thus guessable or easily crackable- password.
- Enabling it, however, would remedy for this issue as the user may use a strong and long password since he won't worry to remember it.
- A password saved within the browser's database (by enabling remember me option) is harder to be compromised by an attacker than a strong password the user is forced to save in a MS Word/text file (case remember me option is disabled)
- Think of a user connecting from his phone where the keyboard could not have all the complicated characters that he was used to type on his computer (whereas the user could do some copy/past the first time he uses your web application for complicated characters from Google and check the remember me option after that)

So you need to weight the pros and cons of disabling the remember me option before you decide of disabling/enabling the remember me option.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to ensure (or at least make more probable) the fact that your user is indeed sitting on the other side of the browser, you should implement multifactor authentication.

As @Jay mentioned (and I fully agree, per my comment) disabling the ability to fill in a password is a terrible thing to do. It is not user friendly and does not help security.

UPDATE: incidently, I just stumbled upon [an interesting article](http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/05/the-cobra-effect-that-is-disabling.html) right about the same subject (from 2014).

Answer (score 4):

This is a bad Idea from a security standpoint.

Basically your encouraging the end-user to circumvent your security by either writing down the password or choose a really simple password that is trivial to hack.

Also from a User experience, you are 'forcing something down there throat' they really do not like. This makes them not like your webapp no matter how good it is.

If you really want to have ensure the End-user is entering the information use 2 Factor Authentication. That way you require a entry that is different each time there is a login.

on a side note, Great your memorizing your passwords by heart but for most people that means reusing the password which can have a much bigger implication.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it depends.  On most of the vulnerability and penetration tests that I have gone through, I get a finding that the autocomplete is enabled on the form.  However; I run into the same issue that is mentioned, customers may be alienated and be driven off.

What I did was perform a risk assessment to determine what the actual risk of having the form enabled.  Overall, the way to get the password would require malicious ownership of the desktop by either malware or an unauthorized user.  Basically you are trying to control a risk that you have no effect on.  So unless there is some regulatory concern, I would not really have too much of a problem leaving the autocomplete on.